# Dataset of documents and user libraries

Tags: data-request, nlp

I'm looking for a decently sized dataset (more than 100k docs) which consists of bag of words documents along with a list of users where associated to each user is a list of those documents the user has in his or her library.  Or even better, where associated to each user is a list of ratings that the user gave to those documents they viewed.

Does anyone know of such a dataset?

I'd really like to get my hands on the Mendeley DataTEL dataset, but they won't respond to my emails.

Comment: explain "bag of words" a little more please

Comment: @albert, that just means the words in the documents don't have to be ordered, each document can just be a list of unordered words with their associated counts.  Of course if they're ordered that's fine too, but they don't have to be.

Comment: ....link to said mendeley datatel dataset?

Comment: @albert, well I can't link to it, because it isn't openly accessible, but here is the link to the site that describes it: http://www.teleurope.eu/pg/pages/view/50632/

Comment: have you asked for it? datachallenge@mendeley.com also, is this a sampling? http://www.teleurope.eu/pg/file/read/47778/aposdle-data-set

Comment: @albert I'm not sure what that is.  Ya like I said I emailed them and asked for it but they didn't respond.

Answer (score 3):

While you may not have access to the Mendeley DataTEL dataset, have you considered other open datasets?

Netflix has an open API that provides a very similar set of [information](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/netflix) that I think might fit the needs of your request. The main features being:

- Access to data for 100k movie and tv episode titles on DVD *(as well as - Netflix account access on a user's behalf)* with ratings information

Through the above, you could hypothetically back-in to a user's "library" by creating a list key-value dictionary that stores the UID of the user to a list of their rated interactions with Netflix media.

Comment: The problem is I need actual documents with text.  This isn't just about finding a recommendation dataset with a user-item matrix, I need both the user-item matrix and I need each item to be a document made up of terms.  I suppose I could use the synopsis of each movie as the document, is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: Could the terms possibly relate to the genre information of the media being consumed by the user? i.e. tags related to genre, duration, year released.

I imagine that you could also connect this to the IMDb site in order to get actor information if you really wanted to be creative.

Comment: No I need actual documents, not metadata, the best idea would be probably to use the summary for the movie on wikipedia or IMDB or w/e as the document.

Comment: There you go! Not sure if this exceeds the requirement of unsorted text - or if that was just to be made a widen options - but sounds like that should do it for you!